# How to make select enabled when it gets cloned by means of JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a select element in a Django template that looks like this:

```
<select hidden="hidden" id="id_horse{{ field.field.index }}_category" name="horse{{ field.field.index }}_category" class="dropdown" data-settings='{"cutOff":10}'>
    <option value="">--------</option>
    {% for hc in horse_categories %}
            <option value="{{ hc.id }}">{{ hc.horse_category }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This one been processed by JQuery's easydropdown and later results in this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="old">
        <select hidden="hidden" id="id_horse1_category" name="horse1_category" class="" data-settings="{&quot;cutOff&quot;:10}">
            <option value="">--------</option>

            <option value="1">Jumping</option>

            <option value="2">Endurance</option>

            <option value="3">Dressage</option>

            <option value="4">Polo</option>

            <option value="5">Race</option>

            <option value="6">Arabians</option>

        </select></span><span class="selected">--------</span><span class="carat"></span><div>
            <ul>
                <li class="active">--------</li>
                <li>Jumping</li>
                <li>Endurance</li>
                <li>Dressage</li>
                <li>Polo</li>
                <li>Race</li>
                <li>Arabians</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

The problem that later in a script i'm trying to clone an element containing this select:

```
var $horse_row = $('.horse-row').last().clone();
```

and it is actually gets cloned BUT unfortunately select element in cloned row is disabled. I know that in AngularJS selectpicker there is an option 'refresh' that gives possibility to perform such operation. In easydropdown - there's so things like that. But maybe there is another generic workarounds?

Comment: I don't see any element in your generated html with the class 'horse-row'

Comment: `.clone(true)` will copy all the event bindings.

Comment: Barmar, yeah! Thanks! This did the trick though now clicking new selects triggers dropping down of the latest select that was in form initially but i guess that is another side of problem. Thanks again.

Comment: You named AngularJS... Why not use select with ng-options?

Comment: jordiburgos, named it just as an example - this project doesn't use Angular, alas.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please do something like this:

```
var $horse_row = $('.horse-row').last().clone();
$horse_row = $($horse_row).find('select').prop('disabled', false);
```

I hope this will help you.